# Styling not applied on React Native components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating my first app in React Native. Functionally my app does what it should do, it shows some lines of texts, one of which changes when pressing on it. The problem is that the styling won't apply - I receive no errors and I imported the StyleSheet. I applied my styling in the render method;

```
//Header.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
    }
    toggleUser = ()=>{
        this.setState(previousState => {
            return { isLoggedIn: !previousState.isLoggedIn }
        });
    }

    render() {
        let display = this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'Sample User' : this.props.message ;
        return (
            <View style={styles.headStyle}>
                <Text 
                    style={styles.headText}
                    onPress={this.toggleUser}>{display}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headText: {
        textAlign: 'right',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontSize: 20
    },
    headStyle: {
        paddingTop: 30,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#35605a'
    }
});
```

Then, I import Header.js in Home.js, as shown below:

```
//Home.js

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from '../Sections/Header.js';

export class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is the homepage</Text>
                <Text>I've made several lines</Text>
                <Text>This is text shown in the app</Text>
                <Header message = 'Press to login' />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

finally I show the Home class in App.js, as shown here;

```
//App.js

import React from 'react';
import { Home } from './App/Views/Home.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Home />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm stuck here and have no clue where the mistake could be at, if there is any additional information needed please let me know, I'm happy to supply it.

Comment: none of them applied ?

Comment: Yes, none of them

Comment: I tested your code and it works. You may need to restart react-native server

Comment: Tried it but didn't work out, I'll create a new project in the hopes it'll work now

Answer (score 1):

try like this
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

```js
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.headStyle}  onPress={this.toggleUser}>
                <Text 
                    style={styles.headText}
                    
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however still don't see any styling

Comment: i see you are making text color white, color: '#ffffff', and you home component background is also white by default

Comment: True, however the text is black, none of the styling is applied. I tried using expo and the iOS simulator for previewing the code. Also the heading, should have #35605a as background

Comment: Also wrap Home component inside <SafeAreaView>, import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'

Comment: I replaced the regular <View> with the <SafeAreaView> in Home.js, without any additional styling - but unfortunately doesn't apply the styling

Comment: can you post the screenshot from simulator here

Comment: I think I can't post pictures, here's a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bxpJdaeqTh5Ve1DSEL-7yoyUJcvnbaM-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Image is restricted,

Comment: My bad, you can see it now

Comment: uninstall expo from simulator, and relaunch app from terminal by pressing "i"

Comment: The iOS simulator also doesn't apply the styling, also no errors

Comment: well very strange, last thing, what is your react native version and expo version?

Comment: I'm using expo 2.17.4, with React Native 0.63.2

Comment: well, seems like you are doing everything fine

Comment: stop server, delete node_modules folder, do yarn install on npm install, and try again,

Comment: Also didn't do it. I'll create a new project, thanks for your effort and time Nikhil